# SphinxQL builder get total_found

Tags: sphinxql

I am using SphinxQL build with zend db style queries sphinx, it works great.
https://github.com/FoolCode/SphinxQL-Query-Builder

I am trying to figure out how to get total_found number from the query.

I try SphinxQL::create($this->conn)->query('SHOW META'), but it seems the return array doesn't have total_found column.
Or I have to run another query to count the result.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just try it and works, I missed the ->execute() part, so it works well now.